# How do I Pass a Dataframe column in where clause of a SQL (Column is of type string) with a Group by and Order By

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 1 column which has a list of product serial numbers.
I am trying to pass a Pandas Dataframe column in the where clause of a SQL. This column is of type string.

| SerialNum |
| --- |
| 7C207300PFB |
| WSE0BTEW |
| 51W0A086FF5F |

```
sn = tuple(df['SerialNum'].values)

sqlsnr = "SELECT DISTINCT PSHIP.SERIAL_NUMBER,PSHIP.MATERIAL_NUMBER,max(PSHIP.SHIPMENT_DATE) as "Shipdate" FROM P_SHIPMENT_SERIAL_NUMBER PSHIP LEFT OUTER JOIN P_SHIPMENT_SALES SALES ON (PSHIP.SHIPMENT_IDENTIFIER=SALES.SHIPMENT_IDENTIFIER) AND PSHIP.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER=SALES.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER IN (%s)" % (",".join(["?"]*len(sn)),) GROUP BY PSHIP.SERIAL_NUMBER,PSHIP.MATERIAL_NUMBER Order by PSHIP.SERIAL_NUMBER,PSHIP.MATERIAL_NUMBER,max(PSHIP.SHIPMENT_DATE) asc
```

gives me the below error
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with string `format`

```
s = "('"+"','".join(df['SerialNum'])+"')"
"select * from yourtable where some in {s}".format(s=s)
Out[114]: "select * from yorudb where some in ('7C207300PFB'.'WSE0BTEW'.'51W0A086FF5F')"
```